# Using recurssion in deleting parent and child relationship in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I'm having trouble getting this function work. This is my database design

I'm working in an application wherein when a user deletes a parent category, all the subcategory would also be deleted, and so on and so fort..
For example:

When the user clicks on the "Test1" category in my application, the "Test1.1" and "Test1.1.1" would be deleted since it is under the "Test1" category.

[image]

This is my database design(above).

This is the code that I wrote:

```
function DeleteProjectPhotos( $cat_id ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM project_category WHERE category_id = '$cat_id'"; 
        $query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
        if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 0 ) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM project_category WHERE parent_id = '$cat_id'"; 
            $query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
            if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 0 ) {
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
                    $this->DeleteProjectPhotos( $row['category_id'] );
                }
            } else {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM project_category WHERE category_id = '$cat_id'";
                $query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
            }
        }
    }
```

But I think the whole logic here is wrong because when I try to delete the category_id 33, everything won't be deleted. Kindly teach me how to do this one.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you considered using triggers?

Comment: No, I think triggers is not related in my problem here because I just want to delete the category that the user clicks on in my application. For example, the user click the "Test" category, and under the "Test" category is Test1,Test1.1,Test1.1.1,Test2,Test,2.1, those will be deleted.

Comment: triggers in a web application? lol

Comment: Yes, db triggers,there is a thing called database integrity...

Comment: Foreign key + On delete cascade would do it ...

Comment: 'A foreign key is a field in a relational table that matches a candidate key of another table. The foreign key can be used to cross-reference tables.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$catID = $_GET['catID']; 
deleteCategory($catID);

function connect(){

  $host = 'localhost';
  $dbName = 'sony';
  $userName = 'root';
  $password = '';

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName",$userName,$password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  return $conn;
  }

  $stmt = '';
 function deleteCategory($catID){

  $conn = connect();
  $tableName = 'childparent';

  $sql = "select catID from $tableName where parentID = :catID";

  global $stmt;
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


      $idsToDelete = getChilds($catID);
      $idsToDelete[] = $catID;
  //print_r($idsToDelete);

  $delExp = '';
  foreach($idsToDelete as $id)
     $delExp .= " catID=$id or";
  $delExp = preg_replace('/or$/','',$delExp);

  if($delExp != ''){

      $delSql = "delete from $tableName where $delExp";
      //echo $delSql;

       $delStmt = $conn->prepare($delSql);
       $delStmt->execute(); 

      }






  }

 $collectedIDs = array();

 function getChilds($catID){

 global $stmt,$collectedIDs;

 $stmt->bindValue(':catID',$catID);

 $stmt->execute();

 $childCatIDs = array();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $childCatIDs[] = $row['catID'];
    $collectedIDs[] = $row['catID'];    
 }

 //print_r($childCatIDs);
 //die();
 if(!empty($childCatIDs)){
        foreach($childCatIDs as $cid)
            getChilds($cid);

 }

 return $collectedIDs;


  }



?>
```

Comment: Yes....After I saw your question I thought to implement it in my local machine. Its 100% working. just change the database name,table name and the column names.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want triggers you can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php on delete category you get it`s id and while there is a return you try to delete by cathegory or by parent

Comment: Ok, so no triggers, and no mysql_affected_rows...then I would suggest you start whitchraft

Comment: Or if whitchraft doesn`t work I would change the db`s structure (cathegories=> id, name; subcathegories=>id, name; and an intermediar table x_cat_subcat=> id, cat_id, sub_cat_id)